# How can I scrape an image that doesn't have an extension?

Tags: image, webrequest, http-status-code-403, scrape, webresponse

Sometimes I come across an image that I can't scrape so that it can be saved. An example of this is:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/plumdistrict.com-production/perks/12321/image/original.?1325898487

When I hit the url from Internet Explorer I see the image but when I try to get it from the code below I get the following error message "System.Net.WebException The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden" error with GetResponse:

```
string url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/plumdistrict.com-production/perks/12321/image/original.?1325898487";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Any ideas on how to get this image?

Edit:

I am able to get to save images that do have extensions. For example I can scrape the following image just fine:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/plumdistrict.com-production/perks/12659/image/original.jpg?1326828951

Answer (score 1):

Although HTTP is originally supposed to be stateless, there are a lot of implementations that rely on it being stateless. I could configure my webserver to only accept requests for "http://mydomain.com/sexy_avatar.jpg" if you provide a cookie proving you were logged in. If not, I send you a redirect 303 to "http://mydomain.com/avatar_for_public_use.jpg".

Amazon could be doing the same. Try to load the web page using Chrome, and look at the Network view in developer mode (CTRL+SHIFT+J) to see all headers supplied to the website. Maybe you even need to do a full navigation in the same session before you are allowed to see the image. This is certainly the case in many web applications I have developed :-)

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. I think you are saying that amazon might require me to pass it some session state, through cookies for example, however, I can get this image without being logged in through IE.

Comment: To verify your theory, I went ahead and made the request for the image programmatically with a logged in session through cookies, but was still not able to get this image. I still get the 403 error. I know that the session state is correct becuase I can access member-only pages. In addition I can access and save every image except this one. I am still curious if this not having an exentsion could be the reason.

Comment: Amazon could be blocking your user agent, or blocking your request based on any other headers you send. Make sure you have the exact same communication from your Java program as from the browser. For this, use the developer tools from Google Chrome to analyze the HTTP traffic (or use Wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like it's being generated from a script (possibly being retrieved from a database). The server *should* be sending a file/content type to go along with that... but it doesn't seem to be, which I believe is a violation of standards.

My Linux box knows full well that that's a JPEG image once it's on my hard drive, because it examines file headers rather than relying on extensions. Perhaps there is a tool to do the same in Windows?

Edit: Actually, on further contemplation, it seems odd that you'd get a *403* for that. Perhaps the server is actually blocking you from retrieving the file in that manner.